# Add data into HashMap with loop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm trying to put the data which is read from sequence file, and put it into Hash Map. After the loop finished, I try to print the content which is wrong.

I've tried to just print the key and value in the first loop, and the result is correct. When I try to print the key in the second while loop, the result is several duplicate records. I can't figure it out what is going wrong.

```
    while(reader.next(key, value)) {
        byte[] value_bytes = value.getBytes();
        data_HashMap.put(key, value_bytes);
    }

    IOUtils.closeStream(reader);

    Iterator<Text> keySetIterator = data_HashMap.keySet().iterator();
    while(keySetIterator.hasNext()){
      Text index = keySetIterator.next();
      System.out.println("key: " + index);
    }
```

here is the result

```
Key: 123
Key: 123
Key: 123
Key: 123
Key: 123
Key: 123
```

If I modified the first while loop like this

```
while(reader.next(key, value)) {
    byte[] value_bytes = value.getBytes();
    System.out.println("Key: " + key);
}
```

Here is the result and it's correct.

```
Key: 123
Key: 456
Key: 789
Key: 741
Key: 852
Key: 963
```

Comment: What do you mean by _the result is duplicate_? Can you put your expected output and the actual you are getting?

Comment: Please post [short but full example which will let us reproduce your problem](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Did you properly override `hashCode` and `equals` methods in `Text` class?

Comment: @Pshemo yes it is, but Text is not immutable.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut Oh, in that case it is great example of why mutable objects are usually bad choice as keys (or possibly why hashCode shouldn't be calculated from mutable fields of class).

Comment: @Pshemo I do not override both `hashCode` and `equals` in `Text` class.

Comment: @Pshemo It's a valuable experience for me. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reusing the same key all over again:

```
while(reader.next(key, value)) {
    byte[] value_bytes = value.getBytes();
    data_HashMap.put(**key**, value_bytes);
}
```

I don't know what the type is, but if it's `Text`, simply copy it or use `String` instead.

```
while(reader.next(key, value)) {
    byte[] value_bytes = value.getBytes();
    data_HashMap.put(key.toString(), value_bytes);
}
```

You will hit the same issue with the value bytes as well, so I recommend you to do a defensive copy of this array too.

Comment: I modified the variable type of `key` from `Text` to `String` and the problem solved. By the way, the type, `Text`, is provided by Hadoop which is a optimized variable type for network serialization. But it seems it doesn't work fine in my case.

Comment: I accepted. Thanks for helping me out. It's a valuable experience.